# Get Text of Custom Dialog (UserControl) from Parent UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog

I have a UserControl as Parent and i am opening a custom dialog (user control) as shown in the code below:

```
        Window dialog = new Window
        {
            Title = "A Dialog Box",
            Content = new UserControlDialog(),
            SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize
        };
        dialog.ShowDialog();
```

How can i get the text from the textbox inside the UserControl Dialog?

Comment: *How can i get the text from the textbox inside the UserControl Dialog?*... what text from what `TextBox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a public property in your `UserControlDialog` control, let's say named `Value`. When the user does something in the dialog, set the value from the `TextBox` to the `Value` property:

```
Value = SomeTextBox.Text;
```

When the dialog window is closed, simply read the value from the `dialog` control:

```
...
dialog.ShowDialog();
string result = dialog.Value;
```

A better solution would be to data bind the `Value` property to the inner `TextBox` control, but to do this, you'd either need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), or create the `Value` property as a [`DependencyProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx):

Inside the `UserControlDialog` control:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    FindAncestor={x:Type YourLocalPrefix:UserControlDialog}}}" ... />
```

Comment: i would like to avoid public properties. i would try something using INotifyPropertyChanged. thanks

Comment: It needs to be public otherwise you can't access it from outside the dialog window.

Comment: Ok i implemented INotifyChanged and everything works fine, i just think that the way i am calling my dialog is a bit dummy.

` UserControlDialog ud = dialog.Content as UserControlDialog;
            if (ud == null)
                return;

            UserControlDialogViewModel vm = db.DataContext as UserControlDialogViewModel;
            if (vm == null)
                return;

            string teststr = vm.DialogText.Value.ToString();`

Comment: i am sorry for the spaghetti code. using `this` doesn't work for large text.